# how to i use SharedPreferences to save activity's data when we want to close the app or back to other activities.

Tags: android

how to i use SharedPreferences  to  save activity's data when we want to close the app or back to other activities.

my code:

```
       public EditText[] edts=new EditText[9];
       String[] etd={"f","m","v","f","m","v","f","m","v"};

       private void addTextChangedListeners() {
    for (int i = 0; i < edts.length; i++) {
        final int idx = i; //necessary for inner class
        edts[i].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int        count, int after) {
                //No implementation needed.
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().equals(etd[idx])) {
                    edts[idx].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF00FF"));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //No implementation needed.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Then what data do you want to save,can't be all.

Comment: In general you should save SharedPreferences in the activity's `onPause()`. This callback is the only one which is guaranteed to be called whenever the user attemts to leave the activity.

Answer (score 0):

initialized SharedPreferences:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("preference_file_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Edit preference

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putInt("variable_key", newInt);
editor.commit();
```

Read preference:

```
int myInt = sharedPref.getInt("variable_key", defaultValue);
```